# Unity3D Calling Android Activity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a question regarding about calling an activity from Unity to Android. I've tried the tutorial here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEKnQgAZnR0&feature=relmfu

but I somehow can't launch the unity game.

Is there an alternative toward this step of process? Best if there is a step by step guideline or a video that I can follow through.

Thanks.

Comment: Have not check the vedio, if you use the method that package your .jar into Plugins/Android under Unity Assets folder to call the activity, you must check whether the AndroidMenifest.xml file is correct, [here](https://gist.github.com/linuxaged/7524745) is an example.